# How to run Import-PSSessions from .Net program

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to write code in C# that get mailbox details from user via Power Shell command.

The power shell command script is:

```
Import-PSSession -session (New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://myServer.myDomain.com/Powershell)
Get-Mailbox -Identity helpdesk
```

The script runs OK from PowerShell.

Now my goal is to run it using C#.

This is my function:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
    m_RunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

    m_RunSpace.Open();

    Pipeline pipeLine = m_RunSpace.CreatePipeline();

    Command newSession = new Command("New-PSSession");
    newSession.Parameters.Add("-ConfigurationName", "Microsoft.Exchange");
    newSession.Parameters.Add("-ConnectionUri", "http://myServer.myDomain.com/Powershell");

    Command createSessionForExch = new Command("Import-PSSession");
    createSessionForExch.Parameters.Add("-Session", newSession);

    Command getMailbox = new Command("Get-Mailbox");
    getMailbox.Parameters.Add("-Identity", "helpdesk");

    pipeLine.Commands.Add(createSessionForExch);
    pipeLine.Commands.Add(getMailbox);

    Collection<PSObject> commandResults = pipeLine.Invoke();

    foreach (PSObject cmdlet in commandResults)
    {


    }
}
```

But I receive an error that the "Get-Mailbox" command is not recognize:
[image]

Probably because the Import-PSSessions wasn't invok correctly.

I need help how to run the command Import-PSSession correctly from C#

Comment: Is the user account running the script a memeber of an RBAC role in Exchange that can manage mailboxes?  If not, you won't get the cmdlets for it when you import the session.

Comment: Yes.
The user run the script has permissions.
When I run it on powershell it works fine.
When I tried to implement it on C# I receive an error.
I think I am not implement it correctly.

Comment: Did you found a way to do it ?

Comment: @VincP. no

    I will try to check it again because now I don't have time to deal with it.

Answer (score 2):

Hope, you have found the solution. If not, please give this code a try:

```
 String url = "http://" + ExchangeServerName + "/powershell?serializationLevel=Full";
        System.Uri uri = new Uri(url);
        Console.WriteLine(url);
        System.Security.SecureString securePassword = String2SecureString(password);

        System.Management.Automation.PSCredential creds = new System.Management.Automation.PSCredential(userName, securePassword);


        Runspace runspace = System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

        PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
        PSCommand command = new PSCommand();
        command.AddCommand("New-PSSession");


        command.AddParameter("ConfigurationName", "Microsoft.Exchange");
        command.AddParameter("ConnectionUri", uri);

        command.AddParameter("Credential", creds);
        command.AddParameter("Authentication", Authentication);
        //PSSessionOption sessionOption = new PSSessionOption();
        //sessionOption.SkipCACheck = true;
        //sessionOption.SkipCNCheck = true;
        //sessionOption.SkipRevocationCheck = true;
        //command.AddParameter("SessionOption", sessionOption);

        powershell.Commands = command;

        try
        {
            runspace.Open();

            powershell.Runspace = runspace;

            Collection<PSSession> result = powershell.Invoke<PSSession>();

            foreach (ErrorRecord current in powershell.Streams.Error)
                Console.WriteLine("The following Error happen when opening the remote Runspace: " + current.Exception.ToString() +
                                                                            " | InnerException: " + current.Exception.InnerException);

            if (result.Count != 1)
                throw new System.Exception("Unexpected number of Remote Runspace connections returned.");

            // Set the runspace as a local variable on the runspace
            powershell = PowerShell.Create();

            command = new PSCommand();
            command.AddCommand("Set-Variable");
            command.AddParameter("Name", "ra");
            command.AddParameter("Value", result[0]);
            powershell.Commands = command;
            powershell.Runspace = runspace;
            powershell.Invoke();

            // First import the cmdlets in the current runspace (using Import-PSSession)
            powershell = PowerShell.Create();
            command = new PSCommand();
            //command.AddScript("Import-PSSession $ra");
            command.AddScript("Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Get-Mailbox -Identity:" + MailBoxName + " } -Session $ra");
            powershell.Commands = command;
            powershell.Runspace = runspace;
            //powershell.Commands.AddCommand("Import-Module").AddArgument("activedirectory");
            powershell.Invoke();

            //command = new PSCommand();
            //command.AddCommand("Get-Mailbox");

            ////Change the name of the database

            //command.AddParameter("Identity", "");

            //powershell.Commands = command;
            //powershell.Runspace = runspace;


            Collection<PSObject> results = new Collection<PSObject>();
            results = powershell.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 1):

Full an interesting tutorial about : [Access Exchange Online by PowerShell in C#](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2016/09/18/access-exchange-online-by-powershell-in-c/)

Get-Mailbox example in step 3.

Answer (score 0):

Use WSManConnectionInfo class to supply the uri,schema to open the remote runspace.Please find the code :

```
    private static string CreateConnection()
    {
        Runspace remoteRunspace = null;



        openRunspace(
            "https://pod51057psh.outlook.com/powershell-liveid?PSVersion=3.0",
            "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange",
            @"xxx@xxx.com",
            "xxxxx",
            ref remoteRunspace
         );

         // Command getLicenseCommand = new Command("Get-MsolAccountSku");
            //Command activityCommand = new Command("Get-GroupActivityReport");
            //activityCommand.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("ReportType", "Daily"));
            //activityCommand.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("StartDate", "03/4/2014"));
            //activityCommand.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("EndDate", "03/27/2014"));

        Command activityCommand = new Command("Get-Mailbox");
        activityCommand.Parameters.Add("-Identity", "xxx");

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            powershell.Runspace = remoteRunspace;
            powershell.Commands.AddCommand(activityCommand);

            powershell.Invoke();
            var results = powershell.Invoke();
            remoteRunspace.Close();
            foreach (PSObject obj in results)
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
            }
        }
        remoteRunspace.Close();
        return stringBuilder.ToString();


    }
    public static void openRunspace(string uri, string schema, string username, string livePass,   ref Runspace remoteRunspace)
    {
        System.Security.SecureString password = new System.Security.SecureString();
        foreach (char c in livePass.ToCharArray())
        {
            password.AppendChar(c);
        }
        PSCredential psc = new PSCredential(username, password);
        WSManConnectionInfo rri = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(uri), schema, psc);

        rri.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;

        remoteRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(rri);
        remoteRunspace.Open();
    }
```

Comment: it looks like you are in the right way.  
I tried it but it didn't succeed to pull the information about the mailbox from the user.  
you can see print screen:  
![PrintScreen](http://s30.postimg.org/gu3rvzppd/powershell_Exchange.png).

The result count is zero so there is no information.
You can see near it that the command works from the powershell.
I added my username and password in the operRunspace command.